# TypeError: Constructor Set requires 'new'

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, jestjs, babeljs, babel-jest

Giving my test suite in jest the result is "TypeError: Constructor Set requires 'new'"

.babelrc configuration is:

```
{
  "presets": [["env", { "modules": false }]],
  "env": {
    "test": {
      "presets": [["env"]]
    }
  }
}
```

Test suite:

```js
test('Constructor Set requires "new"', () => {
  class A extends Set {
    constructor(...arg) {
      super(...arg);
      this.add(10);
    }
  }

  const a = new A([1, 2]);
  expect([...a][2]).toEqual(10);
});
```

It is expected that the test should pass. Instead, the Error appears:

```
TypeError: Constructor Set requires 'new'
        at A.Set (<anonymous>)

      1 | test('Constructor Set requires "new"', () => {
      2 |   class A extends Set {
    > 3 |     constructor(...arg) {
        |                         ^
      4 |       super(...arg);
      5 |       this.add(10);
      6 |     }
```

Comment: What if you set `"presets": ["env"]`. Remove extra square bracket wrap

Comment: It does not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve the issue it is necessary to set the targets for `preset-env` plugin. For `jest` it is `node`. (It can be placed in the `"test"` section of `.babelrc`)

```
"env": {
  "test": {
    "presets": [["env", { "targets": { "node": true } }]]
   }
 }
```